# How can I construct a bar chart with two drop downs menus

Tags: python, plotly-dash

How do I construct a bar chart in dash with two drop down menus? In my example the data is stored as follows, which makes it different than other examples:

[table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDahy.png)

I understand how to do it with one dropdown and have tried a few things for the second. However, I cant figure out how the function would need to look like with the second input.

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('cities.xlsx',engine='openpyxl')

app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div([
        html.Div([
            dcc.Dropdown(
            id= "selected_statistic",
            options=[
            {'label': 'Population', 'value': 'pop'},
            {'label': 'Area', 'value': 'a'},
            {'label': 'Density', 'value': 'dens'}
        ],
            value='pop')
],          style={'width': '48%', 'display': 'inline-block'}),

        html.Div([
            dcc.Dropdown(
            id= "year",
            options=[
            {'label': '1990', 'value': '1990'},
            {'label': '2000', 'value': '2000'},
            {'label': '2010', 'value': '2010'},
            {'label': '2020', 'value': '2020'}
        ],
        value='1990'),

],          style = {'width': '48%', 'float': 'right', 'display': 'inline-block'}),
        dcc.Graph(id='graph')
])

@app.callback(Output('graph', 'figure'),
              [Input('selected_statistic', 'value'),
               Input('year', 'value')])

def update_figure(selected_statistic,year):
    df2 = df[df["statistic"] == selected_statistic]
    fig = px.bar(df2[df2],
                x="city",
                y="value",
                color="city")
    return fig


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```py
df2 = df[df["statistic"].eq(selected_statistic) && df["year"].eq(year)]
```

assuming that your df has a `year` column.